# Referring Internet Explorer - Using Internet Explorer Object Model

Tags: vbscript

I wanted to create a Internet Explorer object in Run Time and I need that to refer or find an browser object (IE) which is already opened in the current session.

Using the below code as Start up creates a new internet explorer object and opens a browser and refers to the same. But how to Create an internet explorer object which would help us identify an existing Browser opened in the session and not to open a new browser window.

```
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
```

Could anyone help me on this. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `Shell.Application` object to [find an already running IE instance](http://www.planetcobalt.net/sdb/attach_ie.shtml).

```
Set sh = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
For Each wnd In sh.Windows
  If InStr(1, wnd.FullName, "iexplore.exe", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
    Set ie = wnd
    Exit For
  End If
Next
```

The above will attach to the first instance found. If you remove the `Exit For` it will instead attach to the last instance found.

Comment: Thanks you, one more info needed, when you say first instance and last instance do you mean internet explorer opened first and last, does it matches exactly in the order of creation time?

Comment: After a quick test: yes, it looks like they're in order of creation (new tab counts as new instance here).